# vee-validate button validation

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I am fairly new with vee-validate. I would like to know how you can validate if a button has been pressed or not. I have wrapped my form with ValidationObserver with a v-slot of invalid. I want user to be required to select a button which would allow user to continue to the next page.

Code for validation Observer that i am wrapping my form:

```
<ValidationObserver v-slot="{ invalid }">
 ...some code
</ValidationObserver>
```

Code below is where i need to know how to set validation which is required for user to select a button from the list.

```
<v-col cols="6" v-for="(opt, index) in options" :key="index">
      <v-btn @click="selectedOption(index)">
        {{ opt.name }}
      </v-btn>
</v-col>
```

and end of my form i have button which allows user to continue. The button is disabled until the form has been completed and there are no validation errors. But i also want to ensure it will enable the button if customer selected the button from the list (code above) otherwise it should be disabled

```
<v-btn :disabled="invalid">
Continue
</v-btn>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your button needs to support and have `v-model` directive applied to it, the `validation-provider` from vee-validate tries to find the nodes/tags with `v-model` and watches them for changes/updates.

So you need to create a wrapping component around `v-btn` that [implements `v-model` support](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Using-v-model-on-Components).

Eventually it should look like this:

```html
<v-col cols="6" v-for="(opt, index) in options" :key="index">
  <ValidationProvider :name="`btn_${index}`" >
    <CustomButtonInput v-model="selectedOption">
      {{ opt.name }}
    </CustomButtonInput>
  </ValidationProvider>
</v-col>
```

In a way it would be similar to either creating a `radio` or `checkbox` input components depending if you allow multiple selections or not.